# scipy griddata produces nan values between samples

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation, nan

I'm trying to interpolate grid points based on unstructured samples. My samples are taken from a log space between 0.01 and 10 (x axis) and between 1e-8 and 1 (y axis). When I run this code:

```py
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

param1, param2, errors = data['param1'].values, data['param2'].values, data['error'].values

x = np.linspace(param1.min(), param1.max(), 100, endpoint=True)
y = np.linspace(param2.min(), param2.max(), 100, endpoint=True)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

Z = griddata((param1, param2), errors, (X, Y), method='linear')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 7))

cax = ax.contourf(X, Y, Z, 25, cmap='hot')
ax.scatter(param1, param2, s=1, color='black', alpha=0.4)
ax.set(xscale='log', yscale='log')

cbar = fig.colorbar(cax)
fig.tight_layout()
```

I get this result.The white area shows NaN values. Both x and y axes are in log scale:
[image]

Even though there are samples in the white area (scatter points prove that), griddata produces NaNs. **There are no NaNs/infs in the data.** Am I missing something or it's just a bug in Scipy?

[data.csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tZ-iAhigbVgwMuTgj4HnulJK-23toRlx/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Check that `error` is finite everywhere (no NaNs, no Infs).  Otherwise, could you give a self-contained minimum working example?

Comment: Updated. added the data.

Comment: The test data don't have an error column. Please provide the data you used to generate the output.

Comment: Fixed. sorry for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the linear spacing of your X-Y interpolation grid, and logarithmic scaling of axes.  This is fairly easily fixed by geometrically ("logarithmically") spacing the interpolation grid.

One can also interpolate in log-space; IMO this gives a better looking result, but it may not be valid.

Here's a more-coarsely-sampled version of your figure, showing how the interpolation grid points are "clumped up" to the top right in the log-scaled plot.  Here the top row of axes is shows where the data is finite, the bottom row is the "real" plot:

[image]

You can see the extreme left and extreme bottom points of a linearly-spaced sample grid are (just!) outside  set of values; this is especially bad because the next closest lines of points are visually far away due to the logarithmic scaling.

Here's a result with the interpolation grid geometrically spaced, and interpolation also done in that space.

[image]

You can run the code below to view the other two variants.

```py
from itertools import product

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
import pandas as pd

CMAP = None
# crude, to make interpolation grid visible
NX = 11
NY = 11

def plot_general(log_grid=False, log_interp=False):
    data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

    param1, param2, errors = data['param1'].values, data['param2'].values, data['error'].values

    if log_grid:
        x = np.geomspace(param1.min(), param1.max(), NX)
        y = np.geomspace(param2.min(), param2.max(), NY)
    else:
        x = np.linspace(param1.min(), param1.max(), NX)
        y = np.linspace(param2.min(), param2.max(), NY)

    X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

    if log_interp:
        Z = griddata((np.log10(param1), np.log10(param2)), errors, (np.log10(X), np.log10(Y)), method='linear')
    else:
        Z = griddata((param1, param2), errors, (X, Y), method='linear')

    fZ = np.isfinite(Z)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 2)

    ax[0,0].contourf(X, Y, fZ, levels=[0.5,1.5])
    ax[0,0].scatter(param1, param2, s=1, color='black')
    ax[0,0].plot(X.flat, Y.flat, '.', color='blue')

    ax[0,1].contourf(X, Y, fZ, levels=[0.5,1.5])
    ax[0,1].scatter(param1, param2, s=1, color='black')
    ax[0,1].plot(X.flat, Y.flat, '.', color='blue')
    ax[0,1].set(xscale='log', yscale='log')

    ax[1,0].contourf(X, Y, Z, levels=25, cmap=CMAP)
    ax[1,0].scatter(param1, param2, s=1, color='black')
    ax[1,0].plot(X.flat, Y.flat, '.', color='blue')
    ax[1,1].contourf(X, Y, Z, levels=25, cmap=CMAP)
    ax[1,1].scatter(param1, param2, s=1, color='black')
    ax[1,1].set(xscale='log', yscale='log')
    ax[1,1].plot(X.flat, Y.flat, '.', color='blue')

    fig.suptitle(f'{log_grid=}, {log_interp=}')
    fig.tight_layout()
    return fig

plt.close('all')

for log_grid, log_interp in product([False, True],
                                    [False, True]):
    fig = plot_general(log_grid, log_interp)
    #if you want to save results:
    #fig.savefig(f'log_grid{log_grid}-log_interp{log_interp}.png')
```